# Count a column in a partition set

Tags: sql, db2

My table ROLE consists of 4 columns, Comid, Memberid, Houseid and Membertype. In a houseid there are multiple memberids with membertype either HEAD or MEM, however a member who is a HEAD will also have another record where he is MEM followed by other memberids with type MEM. My requirement is to partition the table over Houseid and give each memberid a rank case 0 for membertype HEAD and case 1 for membertype MEM and so on, however a memberid who is HEAD ends up getting two ranks 0 and 1, i just have to give him one rank 0 and move on to other members as rank 1,2,3 and so on, there can only be 1 HEAD in one HOUSEID. This is what i tried but without success

```
select Comid, Memberid, Houseid, Membertype,
       rank() over (partition by Houseid, case when MEMBERTYPE 'HEAD' then 0 else 1 end)
from ROLE
```

My query works but MEMBERTYPE='HEAD' ends up getting two rank 0 and 1, i want only rank 0 for HEAD and exclude the record where he is MEM.

Comment: Please tag your question only with the database you are actually using.  It is clearly not MySQL, because ranking functions are not supported in it.

Comment: I agree, thanks for taking care of that.

Comment: Both DB2 and Oracle, that's a very uncommon combination. (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 0):

You are going need to different levels of window functions.  The first assigns "HEAD" to all rows for a household head.  The second does the `rank()`:

```
select Comid, Memberid, Houseid, Membertype,
       rank() over (partition by Houseid order by isHead, memberid) as seqnum
from (select r.*,
             max(case when membertype = 'HEAD' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by HouseId) as isHead
      from ROLE r
     ) r;
```

Comment: @sqlprg . . . Oops, didn't put the alias inside the subquery.

Comment: this fixed the subquery alias, thanks, but i still get an error saying the r.* is not specified in the group by clause